# Как сократить большой .htaccess ?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Помогите настроить правила.

В базе данных имеется больше 1000 городов, 
 хочу чтобы каждый город открывался с добавлением имени города в урл.

делаю так

```
    RewriteRule ^nsk/(.*)$ /$1?regionid=54&cityid=783 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^msk/(.*)$ /$1?regionid=77&cityid=702 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^spb/(.*)$ /$1?regionid=78&cityid=501 [QSA,L]

 ...
 и т.д.
```

Получается очень много RewriteRule. 
 Больше 1000 строк в .htaccess помоему не очень красиво и быстро.
 Все данные о городе (Имя, анг. название, ид региона и города) лежат в бд mysql.

Возможно есть какойто вариант сократить это?
 Или как-то можно брать всё из стороннего php файла где это берётся из БД?
 Как лучше реализовать?

Или 1500 RewriteRule это нормально? О_о

---

Добавлено.

Спасибо, только не могу понять в чём новая проблема:
по ссылке http://site.local/novosib/levayapapk/result.php
открывается http://site.local/result.php?city=novosib
а не   http://site.local/hghgh/result.php?city=novosib

т.е. levayapapk теряется, помоему дело в жадности.

а в паре с функцией добавления слеша в конце (для удаления дублей) вообще корявость получается. Но только на вложенных папках в примере выше. с http://site.local/novosib/result.php всё ОК

```
#Передаём имя несуществующей папки в виде переменной - для городов
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]*)/(.*)$ /$2?f_city=$1 [QSA,L]

#Редирект на страницу со слешем вконце
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)(?<!/)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: а $1 это index.php я так полагаю?

Comment: не только, это любой скрипт.

просто с указанием папки-города к примеру msk/ этому скрипту должны передаваться параметры этого города ?regionid=77&cityid=702

id можно получать и в скрипте (+ 1 запрос), но нужно знать имя города

Comment: Первую проблему понял, это из за QSA, и потомучто это правило запускается многократно, но как решить это не знаю.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/75885/

Comment: решил с помошью http://habrahabr.ru/post/75885/

Comment: Вообще я бы сделал RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfile.php?action=$1
а там уже explode("/", $_GET['action']) и рулил бы внутри скрипта. Когда то я тоже пробовал раписать для каждоого действия отдельно все, в конце концов файл вырос до примерно 100 правил и я начал просто в них путаться, потратил время на небольшое переписывание index.php и поставил вышенаписанное правило -- все стало просто и прозрачно и удобно для управления. Подумайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$2?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

если без ограничений

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{3})/(.*)$ /$2?city=$1 [QSA,L]
```

если ограничить сокращение города 3мя буквами

дальше уже внутри пхп разгребайте входящее, видимо придется составить таблицу сокращений и из id

Comment: ограничений нет, ибо 3мя буквами не сократишь 1500 городов

вариант рабочий, только он захватывает и /css/style.css и images/newtab.png
короче всё в папках, ИМХО тут либо настраивать исключения перечислением всего кроме городов, либо перечислением, опять же, всех доступных городов.

ещё как рабочий вариант можно перед городом писать чтото типа site.com/city-nsk/ , c-msk , но по моему это не очень красиво.

Comment: ну пару строк почитать про htaccess и сразу же найдется

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

:)

Comment: Точно, спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: почитайте сайт http://htaccess.net.ru/ очень много полезных примеров по htaccess

Comment: Спасибо, только не могу понять в чём новая проблема:
по ссылке http://site.local/novosib/levayapapk/result.php
открывается http://site.local/result.php?city=novosib
а не   http://site.local/hghgh/result.php?city=novosib

т.е. levayapapk теряется

в вопросе выше расписал подробней.
-Добавлено- 
Первую проблему понял, это из за QSA, и потомучто это правило запускается многократно, но как решить это не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите одно правило RewriteRule по регулярному выражению, а на PHP сделайте то, что нужно. Иначе давайте подробную информацию

Comment: помогите тогда составить регулярку RewriteRule которая брала бы Только города не трогая остальные папки.

Какая подробная информация нужна? вроде расписал в вопросе, если где то не понятно, скажите - распишу подробней.

нужно чтоб по моей базе городов 
Имя города, анг. название города, ид региона и города

открывались ссылки вида
site.com/анг. название города
пример
site.com/novosibirsk
site.com/moskva
и тд

и ид города и регион передавались запрошенному скрипту, например в виде regionid=77&cityid=702

пример 
site.com/moskva/info.php?page=2 -> site.com/info.php?regionid=77&cityid=702&page=2

Comment: @unknown да вы вообще все несуществующие файлы отправляйте на роутер (router.php) , а он уж сам пусть разберется какие файлы инклюдить.